# If i buy a used computer that has no hard drive is windows recoverable?ble

Tags: msata

Bought a used Gigabyte s11 slate pc that was running won 8.1.
The hard drive was kept buy previous owner. Does this mean i cannot recover Windows 8.1 when instaling a new drive?
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the Windows license? Or are you asking about restoring the previous installation of Windows?

Answer (score 3):

It depends how the Windows License is stored on said computer. Most Laptops and handheld devices have the license stored in the ACPI tables, which is on a chip on the motherboard, and therefore, the license stays with the device, not the HDD. How that is done with the specific device you have mentioned, I cannot tell, since these things are mostly not documented. But since it is a handheld device, I expect the license to be stored in the ACPI tables.

As for the OS itself, no, you cannot simply restore it, you will have to find a way to reinstall it.